# Are some linear combinations of standard basis vectors linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

If e1, e2, and e3 are the standard basis vectors for R3 , then B = {e1, e1 − e2, e2 + e3} is a basis for R3.

This is true, but I do not know why.

Isn't B linearly dependent, because some vectors in the set can be expressed as a linear combination of other vectors in the set. Therefore B cannot be a basis.

Comment: It is not true that some elements of $B$ can be written as linear combinations of other vectors in $B$.  That they can be written as linear combinations of some other vectors isn't relevant.

Comment: To show that they span $\mathbb R^3$, argue that $e_1, e_2, e_3$ are all in the span of $B$.

Comment: "*some vectors in the set can be expressed as a linear combination of other vectors in the set*" $\;-\;$ Can you show how?